# How to update c++ tags automatically in Atom

Tags: c++, ctags, atom-editor

I am trying to use atom editor for my opengl project.
I used ctags to generate indexes for my local project, but I was looking for something that can automatically update indexes while I am coding.
In case, if there isn't any plug-in for atom to automatically updates indexes, Is there a way to load all the ctags for all my libraries globally? so that I can have autocompletion when I type std:: without having a local copy of my all tags in my project

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`symbol-gen` package](https://atom.io/packages/symbol-gen) to generate ctags symbols file for your project (based on the [`.ctags`](https://github.com/weskinner/symbol-gen/blob/master/lib/.ctags) option file).

You can install it from *Atom Package Manager* by: `apm install symbol-gen`.

Also make sure that [`symbols-view` package](https://atom.io/packages/symbols-view) is enabled by: `apm enable symbols-view`.

Then hit <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> (on macOS) to generate tags file for your project.